# Getting HTTP 401 Error when using Camel-http4 with proxy and sslcontext

Tags: apache-camel, http-proxy, http-status-code-401, camel-http

I have existing connection using http4(proxyAuthScheme=http4 and endpoint starts with https://<>) and using proxy and using sslContextParametersRef. it was working fine before.

now we have upgraded our new proxy with new proxy and i am started seeing HTTP 401 Error.

all the credentials correct and working before.

https4://test.org/DownloadHandler.ashx?proxyAuthHost=&authPassword=&bridgeEndpoint=true&authUsername=&proxyAuthScheme=http4&proxyAuthPort=&
throwExceptionOnFailure=true&sslContextParametersRef=sslContextParameters&proxyAuthPassword=&disconnect=true&okStatusCodeRange=200-299&
proxyAuthUsername=

sslContext is configured with correct key store and trust store and with TLSv1.2.

all this configuration working before and with new proxy server entry, i am getting HTTP 401 Error.

also i removed proxyAuthScheme=http4  from endpoint uri and i was getting ssl unverified error which is same as in this post. ( https://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Using-the-HTTP4-component-to-make-a-HTTPS-call-behind-proxy-sever-td5719105.html )

any help here would be appreciated.